# MySQL data not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I am working on a notification script for my site. I can't get the info to insert into the DB. Everything else using these functions worked, except the notification insert. It's sending the notification to the creator of a thread on my forum script, so I put a query where it grabs the data from the forums. query() is a predefined function and $id was already set up in the script.

Here's my code:

```
// Notifications
$eee = "SELECT * FROM forums WHERE id = $id";
$eeee = query($eee);
while($notif = mysqli_fetch_assoc($eeee)){
$query3 = "INSERT INTO notifications (username, purpose, url, from) VALUES ('$notif[creator]', 'commented on your thread', '/forums/view_topic.php?id=$id', '$_SESSION[username]')";
$active3 = mysqli_query(db(), $query3);
}
```

I tried the "or die(mysqli_error(db)), but it just died and returned nothing. I would appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: What's the function `query();`?

Comment: query(); just activates a MySQLi query while already adding the connection variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the backticks around the colum name "from" in the columns list.

Like this

```
INSERT INTO notifications (`username`, `purpose`, `url`, `from`)
```

Without backticks "from" gets interpreted as mysql keyword. That would cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotes around the string keys when you are accessing them in an array.

Your query3 should be:

```
$query3 = "INSERT INTO notifications (username, purpose, url, from)
           VALUES ('$notif[\"creator\"]', 'commented on your thread',
                   '/forums/view_topic.php?id=$id', '$_SESSION[\"username\"]')";
$active3 = mysqli_query(db(), $query3);
```